# open_basedir not being set correctly

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mediatemple, open-basedir

This might be a little to server focused, but I hope someone can help.

I have a PHP CodeIgniter application that I am trying to set up to have the configuration files (like application/config/database.php) set on the server (or local computer) so they are not in github (so database password isn't tracked) and it makes everything easier.

So I have it working perfectly on local host, basically it goes back to:

```
/path_before_httpdocs/config/development/config.php
```

but on the server I have the folder structure set up, but I get this error:

```
Warning: require(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/config/staging/config.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpsdocs/:/tmp/) 
in /home/mysite/staging/deploy/releases/20130312155222/httpdocs/application/config/config.php on line 12
```

so first thing I did was go to php.ini file and see what it was.  It wasn't set, so I set it to the php.ini then restarted httpd. So now if I run phpinfo() i see this:

```
Directive    |        Local Value                                                                                                           |        Master Value
open_basedir | /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpsdocs/:/tmp/ | /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/config/staging/:/tmp/
```

I still get the error.  So next thing I did was try

```
ini_set('open_basedir', '/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/config/staging/:/tmp/');
```

this also did not work.  So next thing was i just echoed ini_get('open_basedir') and this returned

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpdocs/:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/subdomains/staging/httpsdocs/:/tmp/
```

so it looks like it ignore my php.ini

I tried to follow [this article](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/514/How+do+I+set+the+path+for+open_basedir?#dv_40) (I am hosted on a DV 4 on mediatemple).  Mediatemple support said they could not help me. Does anyone here have any ideas?  I can also provide more information if needed.

Comment: Are you **definitely** editing the .ini file returned by `phpinfo()`? And are you restarting your web server each time?

Comment: I am because phpinfo is changing as I make edits and yes i am restart httpd each time

Comment: if there is no risk exposing my phpinfo i can send you the link so you can see the error

Answer (score 0):

I finally came with an answer. In Plesk I was able to set php settings and define open_basedir.